# Is it possible to secure public api keys?

Tags: api, security

I am working on a webserver which uses `rollbarApiKey` and `segmentApiKey` to send data analytics and error logs to relevent hosts.

My understanding is that i have to expose the API keys, which i am currently doing in a /deploy-config.js file. Is it possible to not expose them publicly? Use keys to communicate with rollbar and segment without exposing on a public directory?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In any case that you don't want to expose keys, the solution is always the same: drive the interaction through your own API, and on your server connect to the protected service.

This will increase load on your system. That is the cost of protecting the keys.

There is no way to send keys to a client and then expect the client to not be able to access the keys.

Comment: Even more generally: There is no way to *expect the client to access the remote API* yet somehow not enabling them to access the remote API…